# Problem converting screen coordinates to OpenGL world coordinates

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-4

I'm using C++/Qt/OpenGL 4.3 to implement an OpenGL viewer and I'm stuck on converting mouse coordinates to world coordinates.

Update: After reading the comments and answer, I found this code to work correctly:

```
    float depth;
    double  mouseX;
    double  mouseY;
    _app->getCurPos(mouseX, mouseY);
    glReadPixels(mouseX, _h - mouseY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, (void *)&depth);

    float x = (2.0f * mouseX) / _w - 1.0f;
    float y =  1.0f - (2.0f * mouseY) / _h;
    float z = depth * 2.0 - 1.0; // convert to NDC

    QVector4D pos(x, y, z, 1.0);
    QMatrix4x4 invVM(_app->camera()->ViewMatrix().inverted());
    QMatrix4x4 invPM(_app->camera()->ProjectionMatrix().inverted());
    QVector4D world = invVM * invPM * pos;
    world /= world.w();
    qDebug() << "world" << world;
```

(from the original question...)
Where does this code go wrong?  Its output is included below.

Code:

```
// mouse coordinates to world coordinates
  QVector3D GLCamera::transformScreen(float mouseX, float mouseY)
  {
    // our 3D view has Y as "UP"
    float x = (2.0f * mouseX) / _w - 1.0f;
    float y =  0.0f;
    float z =  1.0f - (2.0f * mouseY) / _h;

    // hard code NDC to upper-right of screen
    x = 1.0;
    y = 0.0;
    z = 1.0;
    QVector4D ndc = QVector4D(x, y, z, 1);

    QVector4D point1 =  ndc * mProjectionMatrix.inverted();
    qDebug() << point1;
    
    QVector3D point3D = QVector3D(point1) / point1.w();
    qDebug() << point3D;
    
    QVector3D point2 = point3D * mViewMatrix.inverted();
    qDebug() << point2;
    
    qDebug() << "mViewMatrix: " << mViewMatrix;
    qDebug() << "inv        : " << mViewMatrix.inverted();
    qDebug() << "mProjMatrix: " << mProjectionMatrix;
    qDebug() << "inv        : " << mProjectionMatrix.inverted();

    return point2;
  }
```

Output:

```
qDebug: QVector4D(1, 0, 1, 1)
qDebug: QVector4D(0.742599, 0, -49.995, 49.005)
qDebug: QVector3D(0.0151535, 0, -1.0202)

# This is the returned value x seems so much smaller than z
qDebug: QVector3D(-0.000938916, -0.0418856, 0.0473429)


qDebug: mViewMatrix:  QMatrix4x4(type:Translation,Rotation
         1         0         0         0         
         0  0.748955 -0.662621 -0.626549         
         0  0.662621  0.748955  -22.9856         
         0         0         0         1         
)
qDebug: inv        :  QMatrix4x4(type:Translation,Rotation
         1         0         0         0         
         0  0.748955  0.662621      15.7         
         0 -0.662621  0.748955      16.8         
         0         0         0         1         
)
qDebug: mProjMatrix:  QMatrix4x4(type:General
   1.34662         0         0         0         
         0   2.41421         0         0         
         0         0   -1.0002 -0.020002         
         0         0        -1         0         
)
qDebug: inv        :  QMatrix4x4(type:General
  0.742599         0         0         0         
         0  0.414214         0         0         
         0         0         0        -1         
         0         0   -49.995    50.005         
)
```

Comment: What is your question? I assume you don't get the results you expect? There are a couple of things in the code that I would consider wrong. So let me ask you first where the code is from. In order to convert a screen point to world coordinates, you need the point's depth. In this case, you hard-coded it to `1`. Are you aware of that problem in general and how do you want to address it?

Comment: Your code immediately overwrites `(x, y, z)` values, which is probably not your intent. Furthermore, your `z` coordinate is wrong in either case. If `(x, y)` have been mapped to normalized device coordinates `(-1.0, -1.0) -> (+1.0, +1.0)`, then `z = -1.0` will yield `(x, y, z, 1.0)` as a point on the `W = - Z` clipping plane.

Comment: @nico My question is: can someone identify a coding or logic error in my code. The code is from a product I'm  writing for my company. I hard-coded x, y, z for demo purposes after this line: `// hard code NDC to upper-right of screen`

Comment: @brett are you talking about the 3 lines following this comment? `// hard code NDC to upper-right of screen`  that was intentional for the code snippet. I just want to get x and z in the ballpark. I'm  ok with not caring about y (my up/down vector for now.) I'll  explore converting z to be a true depth into the screen. Thanks.

Comment: After making my last comments, I'm  thinking I  have a problem associating mouseY with z.  I'll explore this avenue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The top right corner of the screen is `(1, 1, depth)` in NDC. You need a reasonable depth value to get the point that you want. Otherwise, you will only get a ray.

The matrices you show are supposed to be used for right-multiplication:

```
QVector4D point1 = mProjectionMatrix.inverted() * ndc;
QVector3D point2 = mViewMatrix.inverted() * point3D;
```

The perspective divide should happen at the very end and not in between. Up to this point, continue working with 4D vectors. Otherwise, passing the view-space position (`point1`) as a `QVector3D` will set a w-component of 0 and you will lose any translations. You can pass it as a `QPoint3D`, which would set w=1, but keeping the 4D vector is the safest choice.

```
QVector3D point3D = QVector3D(point1) / point1.w();
```

I would also suggest, naming the intermediate results reasonably (not just `pointX`). Name them `pointClipSpace`, `pointViewSpace`, `pointWorldSpace` or similar.

Again, deciding for an NDC depth is very important to get an interpretable result.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my original question with code that now works.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but it won't show yet since I just joined.